# How to validate values within column of arrays with Great Expectations?

Tags: pandas, great-expectations

This is the very first time I work with GX, so this might be some simple question.

I have this pandas DataFrame, made of a column of strings, and another one of arrays:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "request_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "failure_reasons": [
            [],
            [
                "reason_5"
            ],
            [
                "reason_2",
                "reason_3"
            ],
            [
                "reason_1",
                "reason_2",
                "reason_3",
                "reason_4",
                "reason_5"
            ],
            [],
        ]
    }
)
```

My goal here is to check if the distinct values in `failure_reasons` belong to an expected set. I've tried the code below, after some search over the Expectations Gallery:

```
df.to_parquet("../gx_datasets/data.parquet")

import great_expectations as gx

context = gx.get_context()

validator = context.sources.pandas_default.read_parquet("../gx_datasets/data.parquet")
    
validator.expect_column_distinct_values_to_be_in_set(
    column="failure_reasons",
    value_set=[
        "reason_1",
        "reason_2",
        "reason_3",
        "reason_4",
        "reason_5"
    ]
)
```

It gave me this error:

```
MetricResolutionError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And I'm not sure how to deal with it, since it's my first time with GX. It's obvious to me that GX is checking the rows element-wise, but I can't figure out what I should do for it to check the values itself. Do I need to transform the DataFrame first every time? Or do I need to take another approach?

I couldn't find anything similar to my question here or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're exactly right about what's happening. The easiest way to get that is to transform your data first.

```
df_validate = df.explode("failure_reasons")
context = gx.get_context()
validator = context.sources.pandas_default.read_dataframe(df_validate)
validator.expect_column_distinct_values_to_be_in_set(
    column="failure_reasons",
    value_set=[
        "reason_1",
        "reason_2",
        "reason_3",
        "reason_4",
        "reason_5"
    ]
)
```

You could also build a custom expectation.

That said -- I'm from the GX team, and it makes sense to me to support this case directly, so I'll look at adding an explicit expectation for that.